# Conceptual Question on Tangent Planes to Surfaces

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces

To get the normal vector of a tangent plane at a given point $(x,y,z)$ on a surface $U$, we can use the gradient function $\nabla$ on the equation of the surface to tell us what its components are.

Also, if we want the change in a $dU$ function $U$, then we have

$$dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} dx +\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} dy +\frac{\partial U}{\partial z} dz $$
$$ = \nabla U \cdot d\mathbf{l} $$

$$ = |\nabla U||d\mathbf{l}|\  \mathrm{cos}\theta$$
where $d\mathbf{l} = \mathbf{i}\ dx +\mathbf{j}\ dy+\mathbf{k}\ dz$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $d\mathbf{l}$ & $\nabla U $

meaning for the largest change in $U$ we should have $\theta=0$ so our $d\mathbf{l}$ is in the exact same direction as $\nabla U $.

So $\nabla U$ is a vector pointing in the direction in which $U$ changes the quickest - but surely $U$ is not changing in the direction normal to itself at all? (Which contradicts the reality described at the top of this question).

Can you see where my understanding falters?

Comment: $\nabla U$ is the direction the surface would like to go if only it had the chance. Think of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=k$. If you increase $k$, then the sphere grows outward in every direction. But with $k$ fixed, the sphere cannot go that way. This is the same imagery as for Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: So its the direction which it _would_ go if it could to cause the greatest change in $U$, but unfortunately it is confined to move on the surface. Seems weird that this comes about; is it to do with the fact that our $d\mathbf{l}$ is independent of the equation for $U$ and so is not restricted in any way?

Comment: I'm not sure about $d\mathbf{I}$; I'll leave that to someone with a better understanding than I have. But consider that the surface is a level curve of a function: $U(x,y,z)=k$. Thus, on the surface, by definition, there can be no change in $U$. The normal is calculated by looking at what would happen if you changed $k$, so we conclude that it must be orthogonal to the surface.